# nmake - illegal character '{' in macro

Tags: nmake

1. Hello everyone!
2. I'm trying to compile some external libraries as a prerequisite for compiling source of MESHLAB (a tool for 3d mesh processing).
3. First I use the "qmake" command to generate the Makefile from my project file (external.pro). After that when I run nmake on the generated Makefile, I encounter the following error :

   Makefile(14) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{' in macro
       Stop.
       NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
       Stop.
4. Line 14 is as follows :

   MKDIR         = mkdir
5. But there is no '{' charachter in the Makefile. Here is external.pro and Makefile :

external.pro :

```
config += debug_and_release

TEMPLATE      = subdirs

SUBDIRS       = lib3ds-1.3.0/lib3ds \
                bzip2-1.0.5/bzip2-1.0.5.pro \
                muparser_v132/src \
                levmar-2.3/levmar-2.3.pro \
#                structuresynth/structuresynth.pro \
                                OpenCTM-1.0.3/openctm.pro \
                jhead-2.95/jhead-2.95.pro
#                openkinect/openkinect.pro
```

Makefile :

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: external
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.7.2) on: Thu Jul 12 19:28:51 2012
# Project:  external.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: c:\Qt\4.7.2\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile external.pro
#############################################################################

first: make_default
MAKEFILE      = Makefile
QMAKE         = c:\Qt\4.7.2\bin\qmake.exe
DEL_FILE      = del
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
COPY          = copy /y
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
DEL_FILE      = del
SYMLINK       = 
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds \
        sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro \
        sub-muparser_v132-src \
        sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro \
        sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro \
        sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro

lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ $(MKDIR) lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ 
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\lib3ds.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ $(MKDIR) lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ 
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\lib3ds.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-make_default: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-make_first: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-all: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-clean: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-distclean: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-install_subtargets: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-uninstall_subtargets: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall
bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) bzip2-1.0.5\ $(MKDIR) bzip2-1.0.5\ 
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\bzip2-1.0.5\bzip2-1.0.5.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) bzip2-1.0.5\ $(MKDIR) bzip2-1.0.5\ 
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\bzip2-1.0.5\bzip2-1.0.5.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-make_default: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-make_first: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-all: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-clean: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-distclean: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-install_subtargets: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-uninstall_subtargets: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall
muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) muparser_v132\src\ $(MKDIR) muparser_v132\src\ 
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\muparser_v132\src\src.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-muparser_v132-src-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) muparser_v132\src\ $(MKDIR) muparser_v132\src\ 
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\muparser_v132\src\src.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-muparser_v132-src: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-muparser_v132-src-make_default: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-muparser_v132-src-make_first: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-muparser_v132-src-all: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-muparser_v132-src-clean: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-muparser_v132-src-distclean: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-muparser_v132-src-install_subtargets: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-muparser_v132-src-uninstall_subtargets: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall
levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) levmar-2.3\ $(MKDIR) levmar-2.3\ 
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\levmar-2.3\levmar-2.3.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) levmar-2.3\ $(MKDIR) levmar-2.3\ 
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\levmar-2.3\levmar-2.3.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-make_default: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-make_first: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-all: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-clean: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-distclean: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-install_subtargets: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-uninstall_subtargets: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall
OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm: 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) OpenCTM-1.0.3\ $(MKDIR) OpenCTM-1.0.3\ 
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\OpenCTM-1.0.3\openctm.pro -o $(MAKEFILE).openctm
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) OpenCTM-1.0.3\ $(MKDIR) OpenCTM-1.0.3\ 
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\OpenCTM-1.0.3\openctm.pro -o $(MAKEFILE).openctm
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-make_default: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm 
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-make_first: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm first
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-all: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm all
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-clean: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm clean
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-distclean: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm distclean
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-install_subtargets: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm install
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-uninstall_subtargets: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm FORCE
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm uninstall
jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE): 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) jhead-2.95\ $(MKDIR) jhead-2.95\ 
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\jhead-2.95\jhead-2.95.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) jhead-2.95\ $(MKDIR) jhead-2.95\ 
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(QMAKE) c:\devel\meshlab\src\external\jhead-2.95\jhead-2.95.pro -o $(MAKEFILE)
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE)
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-make_default: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) 
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-make_first: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) first
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-all: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) all
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-clean: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) clean
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-distclean: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) distclean
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-install_subtargets: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) install
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-uninstall_subtargets: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE) FORCE
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE) uninstall

Makefile: external.pro  ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\qmake.conf ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\qconfig.pri \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\modules\qt_webkit_version.pri \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\debug.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\debug_and_release.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\default_post.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\exceptions.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\stl.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\shared.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\embed_manifest_exe.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\embed_manifest_dll.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\thread.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\moc.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\windows.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\resources.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\uic.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\lex.prf \
        ..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\include_source_dir.prf
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile external.pro
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\qconfig.pri:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\modules\qt_webkit_version.pri:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\debug.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\debug_and_release.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\default_post.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\exceptions.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\stl.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\shared.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\embed_manifest_exe.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\embed_manifest_dll.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\qt.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\thread.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\moc.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\win32\windows.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\resources.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\uic.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\lex.prf:
..\..\..\..\Qt\4.7.2\mkspecs\features\include_source_dir.prf:
qmake: qmake_all FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile external.pro

qmake_all: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-qmake_all sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-qmake_all sub-muparser_v132-src-qmake_all sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-qmake_all sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-qmake_all sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-qmake_all FORCE

make_default: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-make_default sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-make_default sub-muparser_v132-src-make_default sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-make_default sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-make_default sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-make_default FORCE
make_first: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-make_first sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-make_first sub-muparser_v132-src-make_first sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-make_first sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-make_first sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-make_first FORCE
all: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-all sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-all sub-muparser_v132-src-all sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-all sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-all sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-all FORCE
clean: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-clean sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-clean sub-muparser_v132-src-clean sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-clean sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-clean sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-clean FORCE
distclean: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-distclean sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-distclean sub-muparser_v132-src-distclean sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-distclean sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-distclean sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-distclean FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile
install_subtargets: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-install_subtargets sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-install_subtargets sub-muparser_v132-src-install_subtargets sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-install_subtargets sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-install_subtargets sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-install_subtargets FORCE
uninstall_subtargets: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-uninstall_subtargets sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-uninstall_subtargets sub-muparser_v132-src-uninstall_subtargets sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-uninstall_subtargets sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-uninstall_subtargets sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-uninstall_subtargets FORCE

sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-sub_Debug: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) debug
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-sub_Debug: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) debug
sub-muparser_v132-src-sub_Debug: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) debug
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-sub_Debug: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) debug
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-sub_Debug: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm debug
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-sub_Debug: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) debug
debug: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-sub_Debug sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-sub_Debug sub-muparser_v132-src-sub_Debug sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-sub_Debug sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-sub_Debug sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-sub_Debug

sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-sub_Release: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) release
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-sub_Release: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) release
sub-muparser_v132-src-sub_Release: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) release
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-sub_Release: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) release
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-sub_Release: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm release
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-sub_Release: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) release
release: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-sub_Release sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-sub_Release sub-muparser_v132-src-sub_Release sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-sub_Release sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-sub_Release sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-sub_Release

sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-check: lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd lib3ds-1.3.0\lib3ds\ && $(MAKE) check
sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-check: bzip2-1.0.5\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd bzip2-1.0.5\ && $(MAKE) check
sub-muparser_v132-src-check: muparser_v132\src\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd muparser_v132\src\ && $(MAKE) check
sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-check: levmar-2.3\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd levmar-2.3\ && $(MAKE) check
sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-check: OpenCTM-1.0.3\$(MAKEFILE).openctm
    cd OpenCTM-1.0.3\ && $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE).openctm check
sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-check: jhead-2.95\$(MAKEFILE)
    cd jhead-2.95\ && $(MAKE) check
check: sub-lib3ds-1-3-0-lib3ds-check sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-check sub-muparser_v132-src-check sub-levmar-2-3-levmar-2-3-pro-check sub-OpenCTM-1-0-3-openctm-pro-check sub-jhead-2-95-jhead-2-95-pro-check

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all
install: install_subtargets  FORCE

uninstall:  uninstall_subtargets FORCE

FORCE:
```

Comment: I think you showing us wrong Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this makefile also runs qmake as the first thing it does (I tried it). Any of the makefiles built by qmake recursively could contain the rogue "{" character caused by the parameters passed to qmake.

As I don't have your installaion of qmake and 3d mesh it hard to reproduce the error. You need to extract more detail from what you have to supply a problem we can answer.....